# Creating a vertical menu alongside a image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, nav

I am trying to create a vertical nav alongside a image (See image form what I am trying to achieve).

[image: http://futurform.co.uk/images/image.jpg]

Ideally I'd like to restrict the whole block to a height (say 400px).

Below is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="navSlider">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="slider">
        <img src="img.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've floated the `nav` and `.slider` and set the widths as below:

```
nav {
   width:28.57142%;
   background:#417050;
   float:left;
}

.slider {
   float:right;
   width:71.42857%;
}
```

This works fine, but I would like the nav to always be the same height as the image, and align in the middle of the div vertically.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No image seen in the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D image link now added. Thanks

Comment: Wow, those are some weird, arbitrary percentages you use for the widths...

Comment: These are just based on my responsive layout, E.G.

Container width is 980px. The .slider i wanted 700px in width, therefor 700px / 980px = 71.42857%  @JustusRomijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Make `.navSlider` act like a table, and `nav` and `.slider` as table-cell. Then vertical-align the nav.

CSS:

```
.navSlider {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
nav, .slider {
    display: table-cell;

}
nav {
    width:28.57142%;
    background:#417050;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slider {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Utg4V/).

Please note that `nav` and `.slider` will always have the same height with this code. If you don't want that, remove the background color from `nav` and add it to the `ul` inside it:

```
nav {
    width:28.57142%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav > ul {
    background:#417050;
}
```

Check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Utg4V/2/)